# Problem with installing packages in Python: python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip

I'm quite new to Python and I have a really basic problem. While installing packages the pip method doesn't work for me. I get this error message:

python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

I've tried lots of things I could find here on the site, but none of them worked. I use python 3.7 (just reinstalled) on windows 7 and using jupyter framework this is where I'm right now:

[Jupyter code of suggested solutions - didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIirk.png)

I've tried everyting above in cmd as well. Has anyone found the way which works in general for windows users?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the failing command and the complete error message you're getting.  "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1" is just the last line of the output; we need a lot more information.

Comment: Setup tools might not be properly installed. Try running: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. If that doesn't work: `easy_install -U setuptools`

Comment: @ PL200 
I've tried pip install --upgrade setuptools and easy_install -U setuptools. These don't work.

@jwodder
[This is the whole error message][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxNyP.png and it doesn't matter which package I'm trying.

'A megadott modul nem található' == 'The given modul isn't found'

Comment: Uninstall pip and reinstall it again , You broke the pip package

Comment: @YashKumarAtri
I'll try it! thanks!